# Cross platform determination of shared library architecture in Python

Tags: python, 64-bit, cross-platform, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

Is there a cross platform python command (or package) that allows me to find if a dll (or a .so or a .dylib) is 32 or 64 bits?